# QInputDialog Parameter Defaults

Tags: c++, qt, parameters

I am learning Qt and C++ and I am starting to use the QInputDialog and QMessageBox. The official Qt Documentation states the following as the default QInputDialog parameters:

double QInputDialog::getDouble ( QWidget * parent, const QString & title, const QString & label, double value = 0, double min = -2147483647, double max = 2147483647, int decimals = 1, bool * ok = 0, Qt::WindowFlags flags = 0 )

If, say, I want to change the number of decimal places that the user can input, I would have to change "int decimals = 1". Is there a shorthand way of changing this while keeping the min and max as their default values or would have to manually put in -214... and 214...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ doesn't allow you to choose which parameters to specify and which to leave at default values.  So, unfortunately, your call will have to include at least all the parameters until `decimals`.

Comment: Thanks for this. It really isn't a big deal. It's more of a convenience thing.

Comment: Answered my question too. What kind of a jacked up language doesn't let you use system defaults? :)